# Firebase Auth C++ - persist login

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-authentication

After having successfully integrated the Firebase C++ Authentication into my App the next logical step is to want to persist that.

So once signed in, on a fresh run of the App I'm looking to maintain that logged in state. However, when calling **Auth::CurrentUser()** it always returns null. The documentation surrounding this API is scarce but I would have thought that would have built in persistence?

Assuming the above assumption is wrong, what is the recommended way to persist a login whilst keeping the Apps user details in sync with the backend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has just been fixed with the release on 2.1.0 of the SDK - woop woop!